# Implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' error

Tags: c#, kinect

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
private KinectAudioSource CreateAudioSource()
{
    var source = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0].AudioSource;
    source.NoiseSuppression = _isNoiseSuppressionOn;
    source.AutomaticGainControlEnabled = _isAutomaticGainOn;
    return source;
}
private object lockObj = new object();
private void RecordKinectAudio()
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        using (var source = CreateAudioSource())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The 'using' statement gives one error which states:

> 'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectAudioSource':type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

How do I eliminate this error and what does it mean?

Answer (score 20):

I am very late to the party, but I should say:

You must add a `reference to Entity Framework` if you get this error while using context inside using statement.

Comment: @Hits right click on the project and select `nuget package manager`. Search for Entity Framework and install it.

Comment: Already had reference to EF, I just updated my EF and that error gone. Thank you but I do not understand this solution.

Comment: @musigh I don't remember anything about Entity Framework and .NET as I have left switched to Javascript and React.js since 2017. Sorry!

Answer (score 19):

You can create like that :

```
public class HelloTest : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void GetData()
    {

    }
}
```

after then you can able create object like

```
using (HelloTest Ht = new HelloTest())
        {
            Ht.GetData();
        }
```

I hope above example helpfull

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when creating a new project I had forgotten to install ENTITY FRAMEWORK via Nuget Package Manager. Sorry if this doesn't relate to kinect but this is where google took me when I was looking for the error in VS.

Answer (score 4):

`Using` keyword required `IDisposable` interface implementation. If you are getting error `'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectAudioSource':type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable.`

So it means like Joachim said `KinectAudioSource` is not `IDisposable`.

Instead of `using` you can use

```
try
{
    Execute();
}
finally
{
    CleanupPart();
}
```

`using` is equivalent `try-finally`. You will only use `try-finally` when you want to do some clean up inside finally and don't care about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The class `KinectAudioSource` is supposed to implement the `IDisposable` interface in order to be using with using block. The classes that do not implement Idisposable could not be instantiated in using statement.

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable objAs a rule, when you use an
>   IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using
>   statement. The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object
>   in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also
>   causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is
>   called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be
>   modified or reassigned, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`KinectAudioSource` is not `IDisposable`, so it cannot be used in a `using` block. What you probably mean to do is to close the data stream ([which does implement IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) instead when you're done recording, something like;

```
private Stream CreateAudioStream()
{
    var source = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0].AudioSource;
    source.NoiseSuppression = _isNoiseSuppressionOn;
    source.AutomaticGainControlEnabled = _isAutomaticGainOn;
    return source.Start();
}
private object lockObj = new object();
private void RecordKinectAudio()
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        using (var source = CreateAudioStream())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply. The error vanished but now I have a new problem. The recorded audio (.wav/.mp3) file that I am saving is not being played by windows media player. It says - "Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing this file".

Comment: @CodeKinect I'm not sure how you're saving it since it's not included in your code. The Stream returned contains data in 16-bit PCM format, sampled at 16 kHz, so if you're just copying it to a file it won't necessarily play "as is".

Comment: What do you suggest I do??

Answer (score 0):

Also adding .NET reference from System.EnterpriseServices version 2 will solve the error. This is especially useful if you are converting from and older version and you have multiple occurrences of "using" keyword to replace

Answer (score 0):

The System.IDisposable error occurs because the connection you are trying to open might not close automatically, when out of scope of where the connection was opened.

Exclude your model connection creation from the using() clause, so that it just remains as :

var source = new CreateAudioSource();
/*
   Rest of code here
*/

Also make sure that you won't ommit the 'new' keyword for the object creation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when creating a new console application .I had forgotten to add ENTITY FRAMEWORK reference in my project.

Adding reference on ENTITY FRAMEWORK resolve issue.

Answer (score -1):

You should add `System.Data.Linq` to your References in the project. This solved the problem for me.